How to make apple watch display off while running app in background
I am sending heartbeats from apple watch to phone and it runs smoothly in background. I am using healthkit and watch connectivity . App runs in background of watch but display never turns off. I want display to turn off and keep app running in background.
I am using healthkit watch connectivity

Which series watch are you using?  Some have an always on display

I am using series 9

The series 9 has an always on display

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Apps compiled for watchOS 8 and later have Always On enabled by
default.

You can disable this feature by setting the WKSupportsAlwaysOnDisplay key to false in the WatchKit Extension’s Info.plist file. Users can also disable Always On for the entire device or on a per-app basis by choosing Settings > Display & Brightness > Always On.
For more details Apple docs

Yeah it worked...
